# Using Python and BeautifulSoup to Parse a Table

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access content in certain td tags with Python and BeautifulSoup. I can either get the first td tag meeting the criteria (with find), or all of them (with findAll).

Now, I could just use findAll, get them all, and get the content I want out of them, but that seems like it is inefficient (even if I put limits on the search). Is there anyway to go to a certain td tag meeting the criteria I want? Say the third, or the 10th?

Here's my code so far:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

br = Browser()
url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=goog+Key+Statistics"
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
td = soup.findAll("td", {'class': 'yfnc_tablehead1'})

for x in range(len(td)):
    var1 = td[x]
    var2 = var1.contents[0]
    print(var2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` and `findAll` are very flexible, the [BeautifulSoup.findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) docs say

> 5. You can pass in a callable object
>   which takes a Tag object as its only
>   argument, and returns a boolean. Every
>   Tag object that findAll encounters
>   will be passed into this object, and
>   if the call returns True then the tag
>   is considered to match.

Comment: Hrm, that might let me do what I need to do. I'll do some tests tonight after work.

Comment: Only issue I see with this is that it's the same tag with the same information. Unless there's the ability to check a child, maybe.

Comment: Yes it's the same tag but you can check the child tags before deciding whether to return true or false, thus giving you an interable of all the tags you want.

Comment: Hrm, biggest problem is that there aren't actually any child tags, just text that I want to pull. Will check it out.

Comment: Awesome awesome, think I got this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to go to a certain td
>   tag meeting the criteria I want? Say
>   the third, or the 10th?

Well...

```
all_tds = [td for td in soup.findAll("td", {'class': 'yfnc_tablehead1'})]

print all_tds[3]
```

...there is no other way..

Comment: Sigh, that's what I thought - I was hoping I was wrong! There isn't even a way using find? I just wish that there was a way to find a specific instance of a tag.

Comment: all_tds = [td for td in td = soup.findAll("td", {'class': 'yfnc_tablehead1'})]          

Also, that line doesn't work.

Comment: Well, fixed - you should be able to discover and fix a typo yourself....blindly copy&pasting code is not a good idea without thinking what you are actually doing

Comment: You're right, I probably should have analyzed it first. I'm still semi newish to programming (about 3 months of practice) and make rookie mistakes. Sorry!