# Using Python and BeautifulSoup to find certain table cell value, then print the entire row?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a table I'm scraping with BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to get it to print the whole row when a certain cell has a particular string. The code below is printing absolutely nothing and I cannot figure out why. If I don't have the for loop and I just print the data variable, I get a ton of information back, so it's something with my for loop.

The thing is, I never know where the word "Check" is going to be or how many times it'll show up in my table, so I can't just look at the index. I've looked at [Using Python and BeautifulSoup to Parse a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420005/using-python-and-beautifulsoup-to-parse-a-table), but it looks like it's just looking for tags, not for specific strings. I tried working with this info: http://www.briancarpio.com/2012/12/02/website-scraping-with-python-and-beautiful-soup/, but it knows exactly what indices to talk to, so it wasn't useful for me here.

Any ideas?

```
nextpage=logged_in.read() #let's read the page once we get logged in
soup=BeautifulSoup(nextpage, "lxml") #BeautifulSoup told me to do this
table = soup.findAll("table", {'class':'table2'}) #Find the table we want to work with
data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in table] #Find the cells for each table row

for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
    if line.find('Check'): #and you find the specific string
        print line #print it 
print "Hey, this did run!" #debug statement
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  What does table look like?  (i.e. `print(table)`).

Comment: @Brian , print table gets me a ton of stuff here, I've included a sample:  <td>
   </div></td></tr>
   <tr class="tr"><td class="myip_tdc"><a href="javascript:showIt('wtt6');">13.111.0.6</a><br /><small>db6</small></td>
   <td class="myip_tdc">Nov, 16 2015 12:39 pm&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="myip_tdc"><small><span style="color:green">Check</span></small></td>
   <td class="myip_tdcr">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr class= "myip_tr"><td colspan="6" class="myip_tde">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible problems.

The first (and most likely) is that you are confusing tags with strings.  In your code you have

```
for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
    if line.find('Check'): #and you find the specific string
        print line #print it
```

The first line gives you a `line` which is a tag.  You are then using the `find` method of *BeautifulSoup* not python, so you are actually looking for a **tag** named `Check`, not the **string** "Check".  There are no `Check` tags so the print line never gets executed.

The second option is that you do actually use the python `find` method which will return the position of the word "Check" in the string.  Since your Check is the only string in the tags `<span style="color:green">Check</span>`, Python `find` will return 0 and therefore your `if` statement will be false.  (I don't think this is what is happening but you always need to be careful that you want 0 to mean `false` and not 0)

I would change you code to the following and run it:

```
for line in table: #if you see a line in the table
    if line.get_text().find('Check') > -1 : #and you find the specific string
         print line #print it
```

This code does a `get_text()` to get the string out of the tag, then does a Python string `find` to see if "check" is in the string.  If it isn't it will return -1.

Comment: Dang, thank you! So what is the difference between the BeautifulSoup find method and the Python find method? Like, how does the code know which method I'm using? Is it just syntax?

Comment: It depends on what type is calling the `find` method.  If the type is a BeautifulSoup tag object it calls that find method, if the type is a string it uses the find method defined by python for strings.  In the above example `line` is a `tag`, `line.get_text()` is a `string` because the BeautifulSoup `get_text()` method returns a string.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that, I appreciate it! Now, what if I wanted the <span style="color:green"> tag, but still wanted it to print the whole tr? Is that a tag I would be able to search for with Beautifulsoup?


<td> </div></td></tr> <tr class="tr"><td class="myip_tdc"><a href="javascript:showIt('wtt6');">13.111.0.6</a><br /><small>db6</small></td> <td class="myip_tdc">Nov, 16 2015 12:39 pm&nbsp;</td> <td class="myip_tdc"><small><span style="color:green">Check</span></small></td> <td class="myip_tdcr">&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr class= "myip_tr"><td colspan="6" class="myip_tde">

Comment: Yes you would do a `findAll` to find the `tr` tags and then do a `find` to see if it had the `span` in it.  If the `span` existed you would print out the `tr`.  If you have problems with this please ask another question so it doesn't get lost below this question.  Also if your original question was answered please accept the answer so it can be closed and out of the unanswered queue.  Glad it helped!